# Why does MATLAB change the matrix dimensions when using an ode solver?

Tags: matlab

I have written some code for some nested for loops that works just fine. It uses a combination of column vectors, row vectors and 3x2 matrices but all the dimensions are consistent. Now when I put these loops in as differential equations and use `ode15s`, suddenly it won't work even for a single iteration of t. It says

> "Attempted to access MP(2,1); index out of bounds because
>   size(MP)=[1,6]"

when actually MP is supposed to be a 3x2 matrix, and certainly was when I was testing the code without the ode solver. Does anyone know what is different about the ode solver that results in changing the dimensions of matrices?

Any help would be seriosuly appreciated,
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ode` routines assume a vector input `y0` (`1xn`) and give a vector output `y`. Immediately after the call to `ode15s`, you can convert back to a matrix, using e.g. `y = reshape(y,[3 2]);` and the rest of your code should work.

Comment: Thank you this was so helpful! And was good for my understanding of what was going on.